# Windows Python Matplotlib Latex Flashing CMD windows

Tags: python, matplotlib, console, windows-10, latex

I've recently reinstalled python, Latex (via TexWorks), and Matplot Lib.
(all on windows 10)
and every time I plot a graph that uses Latex in some text, I get a huge number of console windows flashing open.

This seems a like a bug, as even this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rc('text', usetex=True) 
plt.title("Hi")
plt.show()
```

Once run and zoomed into, creates about 20 seconds of flashing console windows.
And that is zooming in on a blank graph with Hi as the title.

The program names that pop up are:

- C:\texlive\2017\bin\win32\kpsewhich.exe
- C:\texlive\2017\bin\win32\latex.exe
- C:\texlive\2017\bin\win32\dvipng.exe

(Python, Matplotlib and TexWorks are all just the latest releases: 3.64 (for windows 32 bit), 2.2.0 (via pip), and 0.6.2)

Comment: I remember this being asked before. Did you have a look at previous questions on that topic?

Comment: I cannot reproduce. But same (unanswered) question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262712/matplotlib-2-0-and-flashing-cmd-window-with-latex-in-labels.

Comment: Do you know that CMD is running, or are you confusing the console window with the CMD shell?

Comment: It is the console window, I think. Sorry! I did look at all previous questions I could find, on the topic, but none of the questions where resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem (spyder version 3.2.8). However, the problem seems to occur only if I execute within the ipython console. 
My workaround is now to "execute from external system terminal", which you can set by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>. Additionally I have an if clause in my code for modifying the figure

```
release=False # for modifying the figure
release=True # for final printing of the figure
if release:
    plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
else:
    plt.rc('text', usetex=False)
```

I modify and change my figure until I feel it is good and then I set my release variable to "True" and change from "Execute in current console" to "execute from external system terminal".

It is just a workaround but I hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem while running a plot with latex from IDLE. Just running straight from the cmd seems to solve the problem, for example by running a batch file which has the command `python filename.py` inside it.